# Trying to install Gametree Linux on Ubuntu 14.04, error when opening

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm trying to install Gametree linux on Ubuntu 14.04 and I've tried using both gdebi and terminal to install it. Both ways, it installs no problem, but when I try to open it, the program tries to update and I get this error:

```
An exception occurred while retrieving the manifest: communication error: request  failed: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol>
```

The program terminates before it can update and fully install. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you, please, share your Python version? If you don't know how to do that, type in the terminal "python --version" without the quotes and copy/paste the results here. I'm asking this because if you are using the default Python version present at Ubuntu 14.04 (v2.7) this will not work.

Comment: Gametree seems to be a proprietary product, so probably best to ask Transgaming for support on it.

Answer (score 2):

## What is happening?

As you can read on my comment to your question, this problem is caused by a non matched python version between what the program needs and what is installed. By default, Ubuntu 14.04 comes with Python 2.7 that isn't supported by the Gametree installer. So, what can you do? Install Python 2.6 on Ubuntu using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). So, read these instructions:

### Installing pyenv

pyenv has a automated installer that can bypass a very tricky installation. To use this, just type on your shell:

```
$ cd ~
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yyuu/pyenv-installer/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

This will download and run the pyenv automated installer. Follow the instructions and, at the end of the process, update the pyenv db:

```
$ pyenv update
```

### Installing Python 2.6 using pyenv

After the pyenv install you will be able to install and run different versions of Python on your system. The version that you will need is Python 2.6, so we will setup this. Using the terminal, type:

```
$ pyenv install 2.6.9 && pyenv rehash
```

This will install the last 2.6.x version of Python on your system. Now, we need to make this the default version of Python on your machine to make you able to install Gametree.

### Setting up Python 2.6 as system default

This is very simple to do using pyenv. Just type at your shell:

```
$ pyenv global 2.6.9
```

Now you should be able to install Gametree without (maybe?) any problems.

### Reverting back

After the installation I recommend that you revert the default Python version to your previous sysdefault:

```
$ pyenv global system
```

If you still have problems, please, provide feedback and I will update my answer.

Comment: How did you reach the conclusion that the problem is due to python 2.7?